# How can I get the same exact histogram in Excel from matplotlib output?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib

I have read other questions related to how someone can export/transfer a plot from matplotlib, and I could successfully complete the first stage. however, there are small differences between histograms and I have no idea how I can rectify such differences.
In order to draw the same histogram in `Excel`, I simply used the following snippet :

```
#get the output of the created histogram
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(ft_mean, bins=range(0, max(ft_mean)+5)
#save hist info to excel 
df = DataFrame({'mean activations': ft_mean})
df.to_excel("{0}_{1}_mean_activations_hist.xlsx".format(caption, layer_name), sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)

df2 = DataFrame({'count': n,'bins': bins[:-1]})
df2.to_excel("{0}_{1}_mean_activations_hist2.xlsx".format(caption, layer_name), sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

because n and bins and patches had different length compared to ft_mean, I saved each of them separately and then, used bins and ft_mean (activations) to redraw the histogram inside Excel.

However my histograms in python are different than the ones created in Excel, here is an example :
**The histogram in matplotlib:**
[image]

**The same histogram in Excel:** 
[image]

Example 2:
**the histogram in matplotlib:** 
[image]

**The supposedly same histogram created in Excel:** 
[image]

What should I do to get exactly the same histogram in both places?

**Update:**
Here is the example ft_mean which is used to draw the second histogram(example 2): [ft_mean.npy](https://ufile.io/mjxru)

Comment: I'm using a reproducible example and getting the same results in mpl & Excel.  It's a bit difficult to reproduce yours without seeing `ft_mean`.

Comment: @BradSolomon: I uploaded a sample : https://ufile.io/mjxru which is used to draw the second example